# How to impersonate core service client when using Azure OpenIdConnect Authentication

Tags: core-service, sites-9.5

We are using SDL Tridion 9.5 and we have configured Azure OpenIdConnect Authentication using Access management for login into CME. We are working on a Custom Page using core service client but we are unable to impersonate core service client since **HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name** always return empty. What is the correct way to impersonate a core service client? Any sample code will be very helpful

Comment: Looks like you may need to get the username in a different way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57191610/how-to-get-name-of-authenticated-user-in-asp-net-core-application-using-azure-ac/57195778

Comment: Abdul did you manage to get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 1):

Try getting it from the CurrentPrincipal.Identity instead:

```
string userName = HttpContext.Current?.User?.Identity?.Name;
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userName))
{
    userName = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name
}
```

Of course that's assuming you only need the name to impersonate correctly. If you want to use external groups for security, for instance, you should probably be using the ImpersonateWithToken or ImpersonateWithClaims methods instead.

Comment: I have tried your code but unfortunately, I m still getting an empty string

Comment: Perhaps the issue is with the setup of the app for the custom page then? Maybe you could check that it has the same settings as the WebUI application, including modules and such?

Comment: I m using the same application pool which is used by Tridion Site. Since the Authentication is done by Tridion Access Management I m getting System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name as empty

Comment: @Abdul: Can you create a Virtual Directory instead of a separate Web Application?